# Dynamic JPA @JoinColumn Name

Tags: java, jpa

I am not very experienced with JPA and was curious if the following is possible.

Say I have a class `Project` as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    private String projectCode;

    private String departmentId;

    /*
     * Is something like this possible with JPA?
     */
    if (departmentId == null) {
        @JoinColumn(name = "projectCode", referencedColumnName = "assignedProject")
    } else {
        @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    }
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class)
    private List<Employee> contributors;

    // getters/setters

}
```

So I would like to populate the `contributors` list based on the presence of `departmentId`.

Is this possible with JPA? Or will I have to specify two `List<Employee>` fields, mapped by both variables, and preform proper checks within my application logic?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
 * Is something like this possible with JPA?
 */
if (departmentId == null) {
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectCode", referencedColumnName = "assignedProject")
} else {
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
}
```

No, this isn't possible with JPA and you'll be glad that it isn't.

You can achieve what you want by using inheritance in Java.  Begin by creating an `abstract` entity that contains all the common fields of your table.  Then you can create an entity subclass with a `projectCode` attribute and another entity subclass with a `departmentId` attribute.

At the RDBMS level, for a simple object model like the one we just built, a single table can be mapped.  In the `abstract` entity, you would annotate as follows to achieve this:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = STRING, length = 1)
@DiscriminatorValue("?")
@Entity

public abstract class Project {
    :
    :
}

@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class ProjectCodeProject extends Project {
    :
    :
}
```

Remember that RDBMS has no knowledge or notion of inheritance.  Inheritance exists only on the Java side.  In the database, inheritance is represented by metadata.  The "Discriminator" is a special column (here named "DTYPE") that appears in your database table that informs JPA which subclass a particular column represents.  In the above, the code "P" was chosen to represent database records that have a PROJECTCODE attribute rather than a DEPARTMENTID attribute.

Using a class hierarchy like this would enable you to have a table whose rows can have either a departmentId or a projectCode as an attribute (not both).  Because rows of the table are all `Projects`, developing common logic in Java to work with the subtypes ought to be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion!